# Merge media query

Tags: css, merge, sass, gruntjs

I have written many media query in the working process.

Like this:

```
@mixin fullWidth {
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 960px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

And used this mixin many files.

```
@include laptop {
 .test { content: "" }
}
@include laptop {
 .text2 {content: "2" }
}
```

It generated two media query in my CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 960px) {
            .test { content: "" }
        }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 960px) {
            .test2 { content: "2" }
        }
```

I want to merge similar query 
I'm using grunt.

If necessary i will use everything if it possible to solve

Comment: in plain css you should just write all rules for 1 media query together ( not sure about gruntjs)

Answer (score 0):

How about combing the 2 statements into one `@include`, like this:

```
@include laptop {
  .test { content: "" }
  .text2 {content: "2" }
}
```

In the case where you're using the `@laptop` mixin across many files you can use a Grunt plugin like [grunt-combine-mq](https://github.com/frontendfriends/grunt-combine-mq).